# Is there a general way to use WebBrowser to click button

Tags: c#, button, browser, click

There are several existing questions discussing programmatically click Web page button using c# WebBrowser:

```
HtmlElement elem = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("someid");
elem.Focus();
elem.InvokeMember("click")
elem.RemoveFocus();
```

This method seems work for www.cars.com. 
The button is

```
<a class="button primary zc-submit" name="submit" id="newSearch" href="/for-sale/searchresults.action"><span name="searchText">Search New</span></a>
```

But not working for http://www.kbb.com/used-cars. The button is

```
<a class="btnRedGradient fL gobutton" href="javascript:$('#yrmkmdForm').submit();"><span class='btnLeft'></span><span>GO</span><span class='btnRight'></span></a>
```

I wonder is there any general way to use c# WebBrowser to click button in a form automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you check out http://watin.org/

You can navigate and scrape or unit test a web site with much less code then if you just use what c# gives us. For instance, in c# if you want to click a button you need to write additional code to tell the computer to wait until it fires off the next event.

With WatiN this is done for you.

Comment: Thanks Nick! But for some reason, I must implement this by myself. So could you suggest some alternative to solve the problem I encountered?

Comment: @Tom, I wish I could help more. I originally tried to navigate a website with the web browser control and it turned out to be over complicated to the point where I had to find a better solution, which was WatiN.